# Call React component with dynamic URL parameters

Tags: reactjs

For now, I am rendering a React Component with a static URL.

I would like to pass it a dynamic URL.

For instance, rather than calling it like this:

```
https://www.example.com
```

I would like to call it like this:

```
https://www.example.com/?name=John
```

And I would like this to update its `this.props.name` or `this.state.name` components.

Can I do that?

What should I use for this purpose? `react-router`?

Or can this only be done from the backend?

Comment: Yes, you can use `react-router`; It can be used from the front or back end See https://github.com/reactjs/react-router

Answer (score 3):

You do not need react-router. Following would parse your url:

```
    let url_parameter = {};
    const currLocation = window.location.href,
        parArr = currLocation.split("?")[1].split("&");
    for (let i = 0; i < parArr.length; i++) {
        const parr = parArr[i].split("=");
        url_parameter[parr[0]] = parr[1];
    }
```

However, if you use react-router you might want to go the the resource. Than the link would look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/john
```

In this case react allows to get the resource in the this.props.params:
Here how to specify the route:

```
 <Route path="/:name" component={Name}>
```

Here how to access the name in the component 'Name':

```
....
render() {
   const {name} = this.props.params;
   ...
}
```

I hope this helps.